# c++ function taking function pointer with a default function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments, default

assume I have the following function

```
int watchVar(const char* var, const char* descriptor,
            Color (*colorfunc)(const char* var) = yellowColorFunc)
```

with

```
Color yellowColorFunc(const void* var){
    return Color::yellow();
}
```

I want to overload `watchVar` to accept functions whos parameters are `char`, `int`, `float`, etc, but do not want to create a default color function for each type.

g++ gives this error:

```
xpcc::glcd::Color (*)(const char*)' has type 'xpcc::glcd::Color(const void*)
```

Is there another way besides declaring colorfunc to take a void pointer and forcing the caller to cast the argument later himself?

Thanks

Comment: Please define "won't compile". Some compilation error would help.

Comment: -1 (it's only 2 rep points anyway) for not providing the compiler error message.

Comment: @David downvotes on questions have been free of charge for quite some time now.

Comment: error: default argument for parameter of type `xpcc::glcd::Color (*)(const char*)' has type 'xpcc::glcd::Color(const void*)`

Comment: @jrok: Is it not -2 rep for the person that gets the downvote?

Comment: @David it is. But the downvoter used to lose rep, too. I thought that's what you meant. You wouldn't even notice in 100k ballpark, anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your declaring a function pointer taking a `const char *` but `yellowColorFun` takes a `const void *`. If c++11 is available you can use `std::function` like so:
`auto colorFunc = std::function<int(const char *,const char *,std::function<Color(const char*)>)>();`

You said in a comment that you wanted to use the function for `int,float` and others, what your should do in that situation is use a templated function, you really don't wanna use `void*`'s in c++ very often.

Comment: Problem with templates is that I need the type for casting later, because the variable is printed out. RTTI is not available, this code is supposed to be embedded c++. Is there a typeid equivalent at compile time?

Comment: @user765269 why do you need RTTI ints and floats support most of the same functions

Comment: @user765269 The compile time equivalent of RTTI and typeid is templates.

Comment: You are right, I was overthinking the template version, that should totally do it.

Answer (score 4):

the function pointer is declared `const char *` but the yellowColorFunc is declared `const void *`

Comment: I did that on purpose, so I could reuse yellowColorFunc for int,float etc.

Comment: @user765269: This is the classic XY problem. You are asking how to improve your solution to a problem of which everyone is unaware. Take the time to formulate the real problem that you need to solve.